# Does it look bad if a new hire goes to an internal career fair?

Tags: career-development, company-policy

I am in training for a new job at a company I have never worked at before. Training is 2 months long. In class the trainer said that new hires don't have access to internal job postings for at least 6 months, and you need to have good statistics to be considered. This worries me as there are some parts of my current position that I don't like and that's why I'm consider switching. For example the amount of revenue we generate per call is measured (so basically they are giving us responsibilities that is normally done by a sales agent).

Is it true some companies have rules like this for internal job postings? Why would they have such rules, wouldn't it be best for everyone if an employee is in the position he does best? My current position spends a lot of time on the phone and they track metrics, such as revenue per call and time spent per call. If I'm applying for a different (internal) position wouldn't these statistics be irrelevant, for example if I apply to work in an HR position why would the first screen be stats like revenue per call? I would really like to find a full list of such rules but don't know how. I would also like to learn if they are "set in stone" rules or more "unspoken" rules, as I can't see a prime candidate get turned away from a position out of a technicality.

The instructor was the one who told us this and he's not an honest man, but I don't have many points of contact I can ask. Tomorrow there's a job fair for the company. I plan on going, as I am interested in working in a different position, but if someone can't apply internally for 6 months it may look bad if I go. I've never been to an internal job fair, and a large reason why I decided to work for the current company is because there's lots of room for growth.

EDIT: the current position I am in is a common entry point into the company for most people. Also they changed it so in training we get trained in everything, so for example we had been trained in billing even though it's not part of the job. So I imagine transferring to a new position/department wouldn't be a complete waste of training.

Comment: Are you paid while doing this training? How far into the training are you?

Comment: Also, this question seems rather broad. It might be better to split it into "why can't employees switch for 6 months" and "does it look bad to visit an internal job fair if I'm not allowed to switch jobs yet".

Comment: @Erik I considered that but thought the two were closely related. If the community votes, I will make an edit to change it.

Comment: The training is paid but what does it matter?

Comment: That you're paid explains why they don't want you to switch jobs.

Comment: In the US, this is very common.  Usually the company will want you to stay in a position for at least 1 year before applying to another position.

Comment: BTW, what are you basing this statement on? "**The instructor was the one who told us this and he's not an honest man**"

Comment: @MisterPositive Lot's of reasons and examples the instructor is not an honest man but why do you ask? I don't see how it's relevant.

Comment: I just think if you're going to make a statement like that against someone you should back it up a little bit.

Comment: @MisterPositive well, there's lot's of reasons and I don't think one act in isolation makes a person dishonest. But to give one example last week he changed the work schedule with no warning and no notice, and I don't think this was even legal.

Comment: My current company has a 6 month restriction on applying for new internal positions after moving to a new position.  I believe this would also apply to a new hire in their new position, though some companies also have a probationary period that has its own restrictions.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it true some companies have rules like this for internal job postings?

It's not unheard of.

> Why would they have such rules, wouldn't it be best for everyone if an employee is in the position he does best?

Only they can know exactly why they have the rules they have, but I would imagine it's to minimise disruption - a new employee in a team/department will always have something of a learning curve which not only means they aren't fully productive for the first few weeks/months but they also take up time of the existing employee's in training and support. Also it gives people a chance to get settled, it's often difficult to fully know wether a job is a good fit until you've lived it for a few months.

I'm not trying to sound harsh here but you haven't even finished *training* for your current role yet and you want to move to a different one? If you were to move roles now essentially all the time and resources the company has invested in you so far would be completely wasted. Sounds like exactly the sort of situation the 6 months rule is designed to prevent.

To get to the crux of your question then yes IMO it would look bad to go visit the internal jobs fair at this stage. Both in terms of your current department - no team leader or manager enjoys having an employee who clearly doesn't want to be there - let alone one who makes that clear *before they have even started doing the job* and also for other potential internal "employers" since they could easily think "he wanted to jump ship on the last role before he even finished training, why wouldn't he do the same to us?"

So no, don't do it. Finish your training, give your current role an actual chance and then you can actually make an informed decision.